# How to pass variables from controller to view in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass some variables to my header.php in CodeIgniter 3.

I'm not sure but maybe there's an error because the header.php is not directly inside the pages folder and doesn't get passed?

hierarchy:

home.php --> \www\pages\home.php

header.php --> \www\pages\templates\home.php

I know that you can easily pass variables by loading the view:

```
Pages.php:
$data['title'] = "dashboard";

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

```
home.php:
<?php print_r($title); ?> //WORKS
```

```
header.php:
<?php print_r($title); ?> //UNDEFINIED VARIABLE: title
```

Comment: if your hierarchy is correct it should be `
$this->load->view('pages/templates/your_viewfile', $data);`

Comment: Actually thery are Templates for every view. So it's views/templates/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your all views inside www\Project_folder\application\views path. Then you can pass variables like easily.

```
$data['title'] = "dashboard";

$this->load->view('header', $data);
$this->load->view('home');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

No need to pass $data variable to both header and home views. You can pass it to header only.

Comment: Thanks, I only had to give the first view the $data array. Any views loaded afterwards will get the variables too.

Comment: No wait. It worked after the first refresh. After the second refresh without changing code it won't work anymore.

Comment: I get 'Undefined variable title' again. But it sometimes works. I will guess it was the solution but there is some strange things happening in my code. Thanks again.